# Does AndEngine GLES2 work on Android 2.1 update 1?

Tags: android, andengine

Does AndEngine GLES2 work on Android 2.1 update 1? If so what kind of setup is required to run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.2+

From [AndEngine - GLES2 - Pre-Release on December 23rd](http://www.andengine.org/forums/announces/andengine-gles2-pre-release-on-december-23rd-t6097.html)

> Postby Nicolas Gramlich » Thu Dec 22, 2011 4:57 am
>
> Here is a short list of the most interesting changes you'll experience
>   in the GLES2 version:
>
> ```
> GLES2
>     Requirement: Android >= 2.2
> ```